# How to structre a very big app in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, frontend

Reaching out to Angular experts here, as i am pretty new with it.

What i am trying to accomplish is to build a very large app that will actually consist of multiple apps and login areas.

There will be different login areas for different types of users that have different functionality, but they will also share many sections that will be shared through all the accounts. Also some users will have custom functionalities developed just for them.

How could i build it so that the code for the shared parts is in one place only so that i don't have to update all installations mannually when there is an update and also at the same time for a user avoid loading unnecessary code that doesn't belong to them or their user type?

Note that i am building this in Angular for frontend and Laravel for the backend and they will communicate via an API.

I have a hard time figuring out how to do the Angular part, the Laravel backend will be easy to manage since it will be an API.

Thanks!

Comment: Angular app is simple to break into modules. Inject whatever you need

Comment: So if i create a module and only inject it somewhere, none of the code from that module will be loaded in the areas that do not have it injected?